# what is the difference between FixedLenSequenceFeature and VarLenFeature?

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I used to specify `VarLenFeature` when I want to decode variable-length input feature, but recently I noticed there is a `FixedLenSequenceFeature` could do the same thing for me, so what's the difference between these two class? and when should I use one instead of the other? I can get nearly nothing from the documentation.

[VarLenFeature](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/VarLenFeature)

[FixedLenSequenceFeature](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/FixedLenSequenceFeature)